# How do I properly reference a Powershell script from an AWS SSM document?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

The [Amazon EC2 Simple Systems Manager documentation for the runPowerShellScript](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ssm/latest/APIReference/aws-runPowerShellScript.html) API call show how to specify a path to a PowerShell script for execution.

I have tried to specify the full script path as indicated in the documentation:

```
"runCommand":"c:\tools\GetTools.ps1",
```

but I get a syntax error when creating the document, even though the JSON document is correct:

```
aws ssm create-document --content file://myssmdocument.json --name "runPSScript"

A client error (InvalidDocumentContent) occurred when calling the CreateDocument operation: JSON not well-formed. at Line: 12, Column: 29
```

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AWS documentation for the **RunCommand** parameter states:

"Specify the command to run or the path to an existing script on the instance."

It appears the parameter does not actually accept a path. It will generate an error as above if you provide one.

The work around is to use only the script name in the **runCommand** parameter, and specify the full path in the **WorkingDirectory**

```
      "runCommand":"GetTools.ps1",
      "workingDirectory": "c:\tools"
```

This format will allow the **ssm create-document** command to run successfully.